# How to resolve: Some third-party resources can be lazy loaded with a facade react-youtube library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, iframe, lazy-loading

I have a React application where it renders youtube videos using the react-youtube(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) library. My question is there any way to resolve this issue without using a lazy iframe loader. I know that html iframe tag has srcdoc that helps with that issue.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.